# Is kernel density estimation a GMM with uniform mixture weight?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, pattern-recognition

recall that for a Gaussian Mixture Model, the density of p(x) (multivariate) is 
$$P(x) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{C}\pi(c_i)\mathcal{N}(\mu_i,\Sigma_i)$$

On the other hand, non-parametric density estimation using kernel can be stated as follows,
$$P(x)=\frac{1}{N}\Sigma_{i=1}^{N}\frac{1}{(2\pi h^2)^\frac{D}{2}}exp(-\frac{||x-x_n||^2}{2h^2})$$

where N is total number of data we have and D is the dimension we're in, and h is window size.

It seems to me that non-parametric estimation is just a GMM with uniformly distributed prior. But I can't find any justification.

Comment: Yet figured the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The probability density function (PDF) $P$ for the Gaussian kernel density estimate (KDE) you have written here is certainly the density of a mixture of Gaussians: take $C=N$, $\pi\equiv\frac1N$, $\mu_i=x_i$, and $\Sigma_i=h^2 \mathbf{I}_D$ in your first equation, and the corresponding PDF will be the one in your second equation.

So, in that sense, the answer to your question is yes: the Gaussian KDE's PDF is the PDF of a certain GMM. But, as you likely know, there is a reason why these are two different ideas. Below I'll explain the difference in more detail and then hint at another related approach which is a cool way of using GMMs for density estimation.

As to why GMM is not KDE: when people talk about a Gaussian mixture model, they typically don't imagine $C=N$. The usual case would have $C$ much smaller than $N$, and one would infer best guesses for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ by attempting to do maximum likelihood using the expectation-maximization (EM) algorithm. The goal in this case is to model the data as arising from some relatively small number $C$ of clusters or components, and the resulting assignments of data points to individual clusters may help you learn something about your data. So, the GMM's goal of clustering the data is a different from the KDE's goal, which is to estimate the density (PDF) of the data (density estimation).

But, could such a GMM produce the same answer as the KDE? Well, even if you did choose $C=N$ and then used EM to find $\mu$ and $\Sigma$, you would not expect to find $\mu_i=x_i$ or $\Sigma_i$ all the same, except possibly in some particular hand-crafted example. I'm not sure if such examples actually exist, but it would be interesting to figure that out.

What I have written above is a typical, non-Bayesian GMM, by which I mean that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are modeled as fixed quantities with no priors since they are not random (or alternatively, with uniform priors as you mention in your question, which in this case would be [improper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Improper_priors) since there is no uniform distribution on the infinite real line). You could also choose to use informative or non-uniform priors, which would lead to different best guesses (in this Bayesian GMM, they would probably be maximum a posteriori guesses) for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

Finally, there is some convergence of the GMM and KDE idea in more complicated models. For instance, it is possible to define a GMM with an "infinite" number of components, as in the Dirichlet process GMM (for more info you can google this term or start with the references of this [Blei, Jordan paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-1/issue-1/Variational-inference-for-Dirichlet-process-mixtures/10.1214/06-BA104.full) on a certain inference algorithm in such models). Since these models can allocate more and more clusters as the size of the dataset grows, they are actually useful for the density estimation problem that KDE's tackle. In fact, they are statistically consistent for that task -- [here is the classic paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-27/issue-1/Posterior-consistency-of-Dirichlet-mixtures-in-density-estimation/10.1214/aos/1018031105.full) showing that consistency result.